# Signal emitter in graph of nodes

Tags: graph-theory

In a graph of nodes, all nodes are connected to *n* other nodes. Periodically a random node emits a pulse, that propagates from node to node, and decreases in strength with n^steps. Is the frequency with which a node receives a pulse at a given strength such that at steps = 0 and steps = i, each node will receive an equivalent amount of "power"?

Answer (score 1):

From a distance of k to a distance of *k+1*, the amount in the pulse decreases with *n* times. The number of people reached increases with *n* times. That shows that the probability of receiving a pulse at a distance of *k+1* increases with the same factor that the amount decreases.